# Unit testing method with input parameters from multiple data tables

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I would like to create unit test method using Microsoft Unit testing and this method take its input parameters from different tables inside the same DB .

```
[TestMethod()]
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=--;Password=--",
   "Table1", DataAccessMethod.Random), TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod(int parameter1,int parameter2)
{
}
```

For example, parameter1 from table1 and parameter2 from table 2. Can I do that ?

Also, can I make a condition e.g join 2 tables to retrieve sample test data or you can retrieve parameter2 from table2 filtering by parameter1?

All ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, given `TableName` property on `DataSource` attribute requires you to specify one name explicitly. What you could do instead, is create a [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) with data you need, that includes joining your two original tables.

Examples on how to use `DataSource` attribute properly can be found at online [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx).